# How to fit more than 29 parameters in an Http GET request

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to write a Method in my Controller class that responds to an Http GET request. The application is an ASP .NET Core 2.0 API.

The method looks like this:

```
[HttpGet("GetObjects/{parameter1?}/{parameter2:decimal?}.../{parameter29:bool?}"]
public IActionResult(List<string> parameter1 = null, decimal? parameter2 = null, ..., bool? parameter29 = null) 
{

}
```

When I go to add the 30th parameter I get this Exception: OverflowException: Value was either too large or too small for a Decimal. Further details in the Image.

I have tried adding as a parameter a nullable list of strings, a nullable bool and a nullable decimal. They all work fine when I swap a parameter of the existing method.

I see this error as soon as I build my project rather than run/ use it. The only change I make between the working version and the failing one is to add **/{parameter29:bool?} (or any other type of parameter)** to the end of the HttpGet attribute´s route.

[image]

I am trying to get all entries of the database that pertains to this object. I check which parameters are not null and filter the list of entries accordingly. I then return a filtered list.

Comment: It looks like your're passing invalid value to `parameter30`

Comment: I have tried passing a nullable bool and another List of strings. I actually wrote a second method with the same name and with the parameters I´m missing and they work just fine. That´s why I think it has to do with the number of parameters.

Comment: your `parameter29` is `bool` type, therefore you cannot assign `null` to it.

Comment: Yes you can assign null as a default value to a nullable bool just like this. `bool? name = null`

Comment: @axelrotter The point was that that parameter in the question is _not_ a nullable `bool`, but that's probably not the problem

Comment: @Moira Just edited the question. An yes the problem has nothing to do with that.

Comment: So will you ever tell us which value exactly you pass as "parameter30"?

Comment: I would use POST verb if more than 3 parameters are needed, even though it is an API which simply "gets" and returns something. With this, I don't have to worry about the size of the payload and any special characters.

Comment: @Thangadurai I´ll Try it thanks. If it works post it as an answer so I can upvote you ma main man!

Comment: @Evk I´m going to edit my question to clarify the parameters I have tried. Thanks!

Comment: @axelrotter no, what is the _exact_ value of your parameters that results in the exception, not what type they are. If you're getting an overflow exception, something might be off with your values.

Comment: @Thangadurai Tried with HttpPost. Does not work either, unfortunately.

Comment: @Moira This exception occurs when I build the API with IIS express. I can not pass values into the Method. I can, however, pass in a value to the parameters when I swap out the missing parameters with the existing ones. So the values coming in are working just fine.

Comment: @Evk This exception occurs when I build the API with IIS express. I can not pass values into the Method. I can, however, pass in a value to the parameters when I swap out the missing parameters with the existing ones. So the values coming in are working just fine.

Comment: @axelrotter.  Are you saying that you see this error when you build your project rather than when you run/use it?  And the only change you make between the working version and the failing version is to add `/{parameter29:bool?}` to the end of the `HttpGet` attribute's route?

Comment: @JohnLBevan Exactly! Or any type of 29th parameter.

Comment: ps. does your method have a Name?  `IActionResult` is the return type, then the parameters are listed: i.e. you have `public IActionResult(`rather than `public IActionResult MyMethod(`

Comment: @axelrotter I can recreate your issue - so it may be an mvc bug... just removing some code to get an MVE.  Ps. The issue's not in the build itself, but occurs when running the code, but before the API's called.  It may be occurring in the `Build` method called at runtime; not yet debugged to that extent.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's indeed a bug in asp.net core routing. Looking at [RoutePrecedence.cs](https://github.com/aspnet/Routing/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing/Template/RoutePrecedence.cs) we see:

```
// Compute the precedence for generating a url
// e.g.: /api/template          == 5.5
//       /api/template/{id}     == 5.53
//       /api/{id:int}          == 5.4
//       /api/template/{id:int} == 5.54
public static decimal ComputeOutbound(RouteTemplate template)
{
    // Each precedence digit corresponds to one decimal place. For example, 3 segments with precedences 2, 1,
    // and 4 results in a combined precedence of 2.14 (decimal).
    var precedence = 0m;

    for (var i = 0; i < template.Segments.Count; i++)
    {
        var segment = template.Segments[i];

        var digit = ComputeOutboundPrecedenceDigit(segment);
        Debug.Assert(digit >= 0 && digit < 10);

        precedence += decimal.Divide(digit, (decimal)Math.Pow(10, i));
    }

    return precedence;
}
```

This function computes precedence number for route template, so that routes can be sorted in order in which they should be evaluated. For example, `/api/template/{id}` should be evaluated before `/api/template`, because the former is more specific than the latter.

Specific details of how this is calculated are irrelevant for this question, so we can reduce it leaving only relevant part:

```
for (var i = 0; i < template.Segments.Count; i++) {
     ... (decimal)Math.Pow(10, i);
}
```

So for each segment of a route, `Math.Pow(10, segmentIndex)` is calculated and casted to `decimal`. Maximum possible value of `decimal` lies between `Math.Pow(10, 28)` and `Math.Pow(10, 29)`. So as long as your route template contains 30+ parts - this code fails to compute its precedence value.

You can file an issue at asp.net core github repository, though I doubt it will have a high priority, because I doubt that routes with 30+ parts are ever used in real world scenarios.

Best solution would be to not use such a route. Use query string parameters, or json model POSTed in the body of request instead.

Comment: Great detective work @Evk; nice find.  I've logged as an issue: https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/3001 - though agree that such long paths are a code smell.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer. Would it be a better idea to use the idea given by Giorgos Manoltzas by using the model binder? Or am I better off with query string parameters?

Comment: @axelrotter yes, model binding is always a good idea, but model can bind to values in various places. So it can bind to query string parameters, but passing 30 parameters via query string might also be not a very good idea, depending on their length. Or it can bind to parameters in request body. There at least you can not care about length.

Answer (score 4):

Besides the problem you have, which it seems to be related with the value of the decimal parameter30 (too large or too small as the exception indicates), i would suggest that you introduce the concept of a model binder. Please check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding) for more info. In short, you can have a class which models your parameters as an object and then you pass that object as a parameter to your action method (and not 30 different parameters).

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**

- Evk's given the [correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49487260/361842); i.e. this is a bug, but also the cause is a code smell.
- The bug is now [logged on GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/3001).

---

(This is not an answer; but is too verbose for comments, and is hopefully useful to others looking at this question).

Per discussions, I've been able to recreate @axelrotter's issue.

Steps:

- Open Visual Studio (2017 version 15.4.1)
- File, New, Project
- ASP.NET Core Web Application
- Web API
- Open file `ValuesController.cs`
- Add the below method (NB: this only has 28 parameters, but produces the same issue as is described):

  ```
  [HttpGet("{a}/{b}/{c}/{d}/{e}/{f}/{g}/{h}/{i}/{j}/{k}/{l}/{m}/{n}/{o}/{p}/{q}/{r}/{s}/{t}/{u}/{v}/{w}/{x}/{y}/{z}/{a2}/{b2}")]
  public string Get(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e, int f, int g, int h, int i, int j, int k, int l, int m, int n, int o, int p, int q, int r, int s, int t, int u, int v, int w, int x, int y, int z, int a2, int b2) =>
      $"Hello {a} {b} ...";
  ```
- Build the project; all builds successfully
- Run the project; you'll see the reported exception.

Checking [ASP.NET Core's GitHub Issues](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=overflowexception%20decimal%20) I can't see any sign that this is a known bug.  Will investigate a bit more before reporting it (I probably won't get a chance to do this today though; so if anyone beats me to it, please go for it).

---

## Full Code

### ValuesController.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace WebApplication3.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class ValuesController : Controller
    {
        // GET api/values
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }


        [HttpGet("{a}/{b}/{c}/{d}/{e}/{f}/{g}/{h}/{i}/{j}/{k}/{l}/{m}/{n}/{o}/{p}/{q}/{r}/{s}/{t}/{u}/{v}/{w}/{x}/{y}/{z}/{a2}/{b2}")]
        public string Get(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e, int f, int g, int h, int i, int j, int k, int l, int m, int n, int o, int p, int q, int r, int s, int t, int u, int v, int w, int x, int y, int z, int a2, int b2) =>
            $"Hello {a} {b} ...";


    }
}
```

### appsettings.json

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "Debug": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "Console": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Warning"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Program.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;

namespace WebApplication3
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BuildWebHost(args).Run();
        }

        public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build();
    }
}
```

### Startup.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace WebApplication3
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
}
```